# Running npm start throws an error due to a problem with typscript config file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, path, tsconfig

When I run npm start I get this error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@components/navbar/Navbar'
```

This is a accurate path and in vscode it doesn't show any problems with it. I only get this error after running npm start.
This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components*":["src/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

and here is my package.json if that is relevent

```
{
  "name": "webgrim-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "firebase": "^9.6.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "magic": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

the offending line of code in my App.tsx file. Removing @components and using a relative path works fine, but I want to use typescript path.

```
// components
import Navbar from "@components/navbar/Navbar";
```

Comment: Did you try [tracing module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#tracing-module-resolution)? What did you find?

Comment: did you try craco yet? https://dev.to/bybruno/configuring-absolute-paths-in-react-for-web-without-ejecting-en-us-52h6

Comment: Tried it... I don't know what I am looking for in here though. No errors popped up.

Comment: The purpose of paths in tsconfig.json `"@components*":["src/components/*"]` is to tell TypeScript that your module loader / bundler, in this case Webpack, is configured to resolve those mappings at runtime, otherwise the code couldn't type check. In other words, it's a way to tell TypeScript about the behavior of another tool. You need to configure Webpack in a parallel manner

Comment: See the Webpack docs https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias